# FaceBook UIAlertView issues

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I used Facebook SDK on my app. After i pressed "Add feed to your wall", the alert pops up with "YES" or "NO". If i choose "YES" the FBStreamDialoy just flash away.

First , click the button " Add feed to your wall" to call changeFeed: function:

```
-(IBAction) changeFeed
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sporting Summer Festival Monte-Carlo" message:@"Are you attending this concert?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",nil];
    [alert show];
    alert.tag = 1;
    self.alertView =alert;
    [alert release];

}
```

Then, press "YES" button. Call this function:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
        [self showAddFeed];
    }

}
```

And this is the `showAddFeed` function , which is defined in front of `clickButtonAtIndex`.

```
-(void)showAddFeed
{
FBStreamDialog *dialog = [[[FBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.delegate= self;
    dialog.userMessagePrompt = @"*****";
        [dialog show];
}
```

Just cant work well. I don't know why? Thank you for your help.

------------Answer is--------------------------

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fbButtonClick) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it after a delay of 0.1 sec [self performSelector:@selector(fbButtonClick) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.10];

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you listen to:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Which should be:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Because at the `clickedButtonAtIndex` function the view isn't closed and this can cause problems.

Edit:
To make it work in iOS 4 add your facebook login call to a method and call the following function in the didDismissWithButtonIndex:

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(facebookOpenAction) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];